# How to display date in PySpark in descending/ascending order in Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to display the results from the following query in ascending/descending order. However, I'm not sure where to place the DES or ASC clause.

```
df = sql("""select * from myview
where date = last_day(add_months(date_trunc("month", current_date()), -2))""")
```

So, I would like to know where to place the des or asc in the above code to get date output shown in descending or ascending order?

I tried the following

```
df = sql("""select * from myview
where date = last_day(add_months(date_trunc("month", current_date() DES), -2))""")
```

But I got a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding `order by` clause after the `where` clause.

**`Example:`**

```
df = sql("""select * from myview
where date = last_day(add_months(date_trunc("month", current_date()), -2)) order by date asc""")
```